# Which compiler is right about inline static members of template parameter type using a Singleton CRTP?

Tags: c++, templates, singleton, language-lawyer, crtp

I made a very simple `Singleton` base class that can be used with CRTP to make any class that derives from it a singleton. I found something strange though. Different compilers disagree on whether the code is ill-formed or not. Here it is:

```
template <typename Derived>
class Singleton
{
public:
    inline static Derived instance;
};
```

As I said, it is very simple, but that is enough for demonstration purposes. An example usage is shown here:

```
class MyClass : public Singleton<MyClass>
{
public:
    std::string msg;

    MyClass() = default;
    MyClass(const std::string& msg_) : msg{ msg_ }
    {
    }
    MyClass(std::string&& msg_) noexcept : msg{ std::move(msg_) }
    {
    }
};
```

This code compiles under both [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/z77T4v), and [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/hP8nW9). However [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/Y88oME) rejects it by saying that `MyClass` provides no appropriate default constructor (despite it obviously being declared as `default`). Out of curiosity I tried using a different constructor:

```
template <typename Derived>
class Singleton
{
public:
    inline static Derived instance{"hello MSVC"};
};

class MyClass : public Singleton<MyClass>
{
public:
    std::string msg;

    MyClass() = default;
    MyClass(const std::string& msg_) : msg{ msg_ }
    {
    }
    MyClass(std::string&& msg_) noexcept : msg{ std::move(msg_) }
    {
    }
};
```

This is again accepted by [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/qYnfnf) and [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/Pffz3E), but rejected by [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/Mxxd1K), which claims this time that `MyClass` is undefined.

The question is: **Is this code ill-formed? If it is, why?** And consequently, which compilers are right? Are GCC and Clang simply taking advantage of "no diagnostic required"?

My gut feeling is that MSVC is wrong, as this is usually the case, though on the other hand, it is usually more permissive than GCC and Clang, so I am curious of the answer.

Comment: `Derived` is incomplete type inside CRTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC and Clang are correct.

[temp.inst/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#inst-3):

> The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes
>
> - the implicit instantiation of the **declarations, but not of the definitions**, of the non-deleted class member functions, member classes, scoped member enumerations, **static data members**, member templates, and friends; and
> - the implicit instantiation of the definitions of deleted member functions, unscoped member enumerations, and member anonymous unions.

In the context of the `Singleton<Derived>` instantiation, it is true that `Derived` is incomplete, but that doesn't matter because it's ok to declare with an incomplete type.

See also: [gcc bug #71534](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71534)

Comment: Wouldn't `instance` be also defined, as it is marked `inline`?

Comment: Yes, that statement is both a declaration and a definition. What the question is, is when is that static data member's *declaration* instantiated and when is that static data member's *definition* instantiated? They aren't the same answer, even though both events emanate from the same statement. In the implicit instantiation of `Singleton<Derived>`, `Derived` is incomplete, so we have a real problem if we must instantiate the *definition*, but no problem at all if we only instantiate the *declaration*.

Comment: And the standard says we instantiate the declaration only. The definition of a static data member isn't instantiated unless it's needed (see also temp.inst/4: "in particular, the initialization (and any associated side effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used in a way that requires the definition of the static data member to exist")

Comment: At the point `instance` is needed (in main), the compiler instantiates the definition, which is of course OK because `Derived` is complete.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. There one thing left that bothers me though. For some reason, despite this working with user defined types, as I understand, using this with the standard library causes UB. From [res.on.functions]: "2. In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases: [...] 2.5 If an incomplete type ([basic.types]) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component or evaluating a concept, unless specifically allowed for that component.". Am I understanding this incorrectly or is there a reason for this inconsistency?

Comment: From the context (section/lead in), that's talking about instantiating library templates with incomplete types (e.g. `std::set<T>` with `T` incomplete). Unless that's explicitly allowed for the template in question, you get into UB. You could run into this if the declaration of `instance` required such instantiation (e.g. if it was of type `std::set<Derived>::iterator` or the type of instance depended on a type trait of Derived!) and implementations will have trouble diagnosing that. `std::set<Derived>` however would work as to declare something with that type does not require instantiation.